# Is it possible to train a perceptron to perfectly separate part of iris data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a perceptron separate part of iris data.

I consider just the samples belonging to the first two categories and the first two features.

```
>>> iris = load_iris()
>>> X = iris['data'][:100, :2]
>>> y = iris['target'][:100]
```

And then I trained the model with default parameters.

```
>>> classifier = Perceptron()
>>> classifier.fit(X, y)
>>> print(classifier.coef_[0])
>>> print(classifier.intercept_)
[ 23.2 -38.7]
[-5.]
```

with the w and b, I plotted the line

```
x1 = [0, 7]
x2 = [-0.129, 4.067]
plt.plot(x1,x2)
x=X
plt.scatter(x[:50, 0], x[:50, 1], color='red', marker='o', label='Setosa')
plt.scatter(x[50:100, 0], x[50:100, 1], color='blue', marker='x', label='Versicolour')
plt.xlabel("Petal length")
plt.ylabel("Petal width")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

and got this

[image]

there is only one sample that is misclassified.

Is it possible to train a perceptron to perfectly separate part of iris data?

Comment: You don’t want that. In practice you want your model to generalise. A perfect model is mostly going to overfit and that is 9/10 useless in practice.

Comment: You need to find a transformation (kernel) that will cast your data in a space, where it's linearly separable.